# Result of Compute function is not being displayed in the TextBox

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page where there are two Textboxes and a Button. And I had written a Compute function to display the result in a Textbox but its not working. Alerts are not being fired on the page.

Can any one help me out here, where am i going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumericKey(e)
    {
        if (window.event) { 
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) 
        { 
        var charCode = e.which; 
        }
        else 
        { 
        return true; 
        }
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function submitMyNumber()
    {
      alert(1);
           var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
        return x.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
        var y = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
        return y.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
        compute();
    }
    function compute()
    {
       alert(1);
    var a,b,c;
    var qtc=document.form1.myInput.value;
        alert(qtc);
    var hr=document.getByElementById('myinput1').value;
        alert(hr);  
       a=60/hr;
       alert(a);
    b=math.sqrt(a);
      alert(b);
    c=qtc/b;
       alert(c);
       document.write(a + "" + b+ " " + c+ "")
    }
       </script>
     </head>
     <body>
    <form>
    <table align="center" style="border:2px solid black">
        <tr>
            <td>Qtc:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" /><br /></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hr:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="myInput1" name="myInput1" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" name="mySubmit" value="Submit only Number" onclick="compute()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
       <tr><td><input type="text" id="result" name="result" value="" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try with different web browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are typo errors in your code:
Update: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2J3Jt/1/)

1. In `compute()` function

   `getByElementById('myinput1')` should be `getElementById('myInput1')`
   `math.sqrt(a);`  should be `Math.sqrt(a);`

The function should look like

```
function compute(){
    var a,b,c;
    var qtc=document.form1.myInput.value;
    alert(qtc);
    var hr=document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    alert(hr);  
    a=60/hr;
    alert(a);
    b=Math.sqrt(a);
    alert(b);
    c=qtc/b;
    alert(c);
    document.write(a + "" + b+ " " + c+ "")
    //var result = document.getElementById('result');   
    //result.value = c;                
}
```

1. Your html `form` must have a name=form1 `<form name="form1">`

   ```
   <form name="form1">
       <table align="center" style="border:2px solid black">
       <tr> 
          <td>Qtc:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" /><br /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Hr:</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="myInput1" name="myInput1" onkeypress="return isNumericKey(event);" /><br /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><button type="button" onclick="compute(); return false;">Submit only Number</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td><input type="text" id="result" name="result" value="" /></td></tr>
      </table>
     </form>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

in this function

```
function submitMyNumber() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    return x.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null; // <-- return
    var y = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    return y.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
    compute();
}
```

on the second line the function is returning, so all next lines won't never be executed.

If I have to guess you probably want to do something like

```
function submitMyNumber() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    if (!x.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) { return false }

    var y = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    if (!y.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) { return false }

    compute();
}
```

Comment: I've no idea why you've placed a return in the middle of a function. maybe you mean `if (!x.match(/^[0-9]+$/)) { return false }` (twice)

Comment: Caldren now its going to the compute function but the other alerts are not fired

Answer (score 0):

Possible mistakes in your code

- Compute function is never getting called
- Result text box value is never set

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a form name in your code :

Change this from `<form>`

to

```
<form name = "form1" >
```

PS:
When you use something like `document.form1.myInput.value;`

You tell get the `myInput` value from the form with name `form1`

Answer (score 0):

Change your return statements to if statements:

```
function submitMyNumber()
{
  alert(1);
       var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    if (x.match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null ) {
        return;
    }

    var y = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    if (y.match(/^[0-9]+$/) === null ) {
        return;
    }

    compute();
}
```

Comment: if any condition will true, again compute will not execute, isn't it ?

Comment: @Nick the compute function is also not working....alerts are not fired in compute function

Comment: @RedSwan yes, but before the line was always returning, either a match object or null.  This way it only returns early if there are non-digits.  I'm not saying this is the best way to write it, but it should get compute() to run in the go-right cases.

Comment: But now that I look again.. @Anil why do you even have the submitMyNumber function? I don't see it called. Do you mean to call it instead of compute in the onclick event?

Comment: Yes i forgot to replace it with my submitMyNumber  function

Comment: @Nick, agree, thats what i added answer to trick. to store the match values in hidden fields. in this way compute also execute and x,y match values will be stored either null or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think Function should be:

```
function submitMyNumber() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    var x_match=  x.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
    //Store x_match in hiddenfield

    var y = document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
    var y_match= y.match(/^[0-9]+$/) != null;
     //Store y_match in hiddenfield

    compute();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of javascript errors in above code i dont know what you are trying to do but correct javascript will be

```
function compute()
{
 alert(1);
 var a,b,c;
 var qtc=document.form1.myInput.value;
 alert(qtc);
 var hr=document.getElementById('myInput1').value;
 alert(hr);  
 a=60/hr;
 alert(a);
 b=Math.sqrt(a);
 alert(b);
 c=qtc/b;
 alert(c);
 document.getElementById('result').value = c;
 //document.write(a + "" + b+ " " + c+ "")
 return false;
 }
```

plus form tag dont have name field. it should be like

```
    <form onsubmit="return false;" name="form1">
```

and submit button should return false

like

```
    <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" name="mySubmit" value="Submit only Number"    onclick="compute(); return false;" />
```

or else form will continue to submit whether you got javascript error or not

You tool Like firebug to locate your javascript errors